# How to read input device in Java?

Tags: java, input, device

I had questioned before about recommendations on what device to use, but unfortunately, I think I was not being compliant with the Q&A policy of StackOverflow, so I did the research for myself and found an interesting device already. Now I have a question on HowTo described below.

I'm interested in reading the information sent by a system on board that's connected to the computer via USB.

The sensor or system on board, is named **iNEMO-M1**, here's the link: http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/sense_power/FM89/SC1448/PF253162?s_searchtype=keyword

I'm interested in measuring changes in angle with the sensors of the device, that will be attached to another device.

The problem comes when I have to read the information sent by this device.

**How could I read the input data from the device?**

I have downloaded the iNEMO engine software libraries, that includes the libraries (all written in C) and drivers, but I couldn't find out a way to implement it in Java. Maybe I should interact with the device through the installed driver in the manchine, but I haven't got idea on HowTo do that.

Thank you

**EDIT**

I could find the API and documentation in the archive. It is finally written in C. In the API there are 2 structs, sensorData and eulerAngles (this is the one I'm interested in getting information from (I think), because the struct has 3 variables for each angle (X,Y,Z), roll, pitch, yaw), and then one variable, quat, all of these must be passed as parameter to the 3 API functions. There are 3 functions: Init DeInit and Update.

Problem now is that I cannot find where and how the device is linked to these functions, and also how to instance the USB device. There must be some way I'm missing.

I have also downloaded iNEMO M1 Discovery Suite, that's a software to test the sensors and it includes some DLL and examples. In these examples I can find a SDK in C++, C# and also DLL, but not Java. Maybe with JNI or JNA I will be able to load the DLL.

Thanks for your answer. I'm already doing my own research on JNA and JNI.

**Edit 2**

I have found the way to load the DLL. With JNA I'm able to load the DLL. Also, I'm using JNAErator to "translate" the C Headers of the SDK to Java, then using JNA's method `Native.loadLibrary` to load the DLL and then being able to use the Java classes.

Thanks for your help, JNA was the answer. I'm now having some problems with JNA. I created a sample DLL with simple math functions (+,-,*,/) but I'm now having a problem because when I'm loading the DLL it displays an error: Not valid win32 application. I will do some searching in Google and StackOverflow and if I'm not able to fix it, I will be creating a new question in StackOverflow community.

Thank you very much. I would mark your answer as correct, but I can't do this with comments.

Comment: Take a look at JNI or JNA. These frameworks allow you to include the drivers in the Java application.

Comment: Unless the drivers are creating a standard I/O stream on the operating system which you can read from / write to, you'll probably need to wrap around those C libraries using JNI.

Comment: Thank you. I'm able to load the DLL SDK with JNA. I'm now doing some simple testing with a custom math DLL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the way to load the DLL. With JNA I'm able to load the DLL. Also, I'm using JNAErator to "translate" the C Headers of the SDK to Java, then using JNA's method Native.loadLibrary to load the DLL and then being able to use the Java classes.

Thanks for your help, JNA was the answer.

Thank you very much. I would mark your answer as correct, but I can't do this with comments.